# Histograms of gray scale images

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing, histograms

I have a large set of subsequent 8bit gray scale png images (50 Hz). They show the noise of a CMOS camera, with the lens covered.

A subset of 50 images is available here: https://goo.gl/Sa3P9P

I want to plot for each image its brightness histogram and export it to a numbered png file.

An histogram example is given here:

[image]

The problem is that my code is extremely slow. **How can I improve the speed?**

```
ChoiceDialog[{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[imageDir], "Directory"],
    Dynamic[imageDir]}];
SetDirectory[imageDir];

fNames = FileNames["*.png"];
numFiles = Length[fNames];

Table[

  strCounter = ToString@PaddedForm[i, 2, NumberPadding -> {"0", ""}];

  image = Import[fNames[[i]]];
  imageData = Flatten[ImageData[image, "Byte"]];
  imageDataHistogram =
   Histogram[imageData, {1}, Frame -> True, ScalingFunctions -> "Log",
     PlotRange -> {{0, 255}, All}, ImageSize -> 2000, 
    BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 40, 
      FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, 
    FrameLabel -> {{"# of Pixels", ""}, {"Brightness [0,255]", strCounter}}];

  fileName = StringJoin[imageDir, "\\histogram_", strCounter, ".png"];
  Export[fileName, imageDataHistogram, "PNG"],

  {i, 1, numFiles}

  ];
```

Unfortunately `ParallelTable` behaves **very strange**: 
Replacing `Table` by `ParallelTable` produces once images with axis labeling and once not ... very randomly.

Here are the first 10 histogram plots using `Table`: https://goo.gl/H3ftw3

and here using `ParallelTable`: https://goo.gl/sk6uHu

Comment: `ImageHistogram` is much faster than `Histogram` in my experience.  Sorry, I didn't read through your code other than looking for which of these two you used ... I hope this will help though.

Comment: `Table` $\rightarrow$  `ParallelTable`

Comment: Please see my comment above ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much to [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) and [rhermans](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/10397/rhermans).

I have used `ImageHistogram` together with `ParallelTable`.
For 10 images the improved code needs on my computer 2.51 sec (`AbsoluteTiming`) whereby the old code needed 124.22 sec. **The speed is improved to a factor of about 50** ... great ...

The only small but important difference is: **I need a logarithmic y scale for `ImageHistogram`.** Is this possible?

```
ChoiceDialog[{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[imageDir], "Directory"], 
   Dynamic[imageDir]}];
SetDirectory[imageDir];

fNames = FileNames["*.png"];
numFiles = Length[fNames];

ParallelTable[

   strCounter = ToString@PaddedForm[i, 2, NumberPadding -> {"0", ""}];

   image = Import[fNames[[i]]];
   imageHistogram =
    ImageHistogram[image, 255, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> True, 
     ImageSize -> 2000, AspectRatio -> 2/3, 
     BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 40, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, 
     FrameLabel -> {{"# of Pixels", ""}, {"Brightness [0,1]", strCounter}}]
   ;

   fileName = StringJoin[imageDir, "\\histogram_", strCounter, ".png"];   
   Export[fileName, imageHistogram, "PNG"],

   {i, 1, numFiles}

   ];
```

**The solution on how to get a logarithmic vertical scale in ImageHistogram was send to me by the the Mathematics support team:**

[ImageHistogram with logarithmic y scale](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104236/imagehistogram-with-logarithmic-y-scale)

Comment: Alternative solution: see my answer in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104328/mysterious-behaviour-of-paralleltable

Comment: mrz you should accept your answer so this question doesnt keep getting bumped as unanswered. (Unless obviously you still hold out for a better answer..).   BTW  `ParallelDo` would seem more appropriate here, though it probably doesn't make any difference.