# Mysterious behaviour of ParallelTable

Tags: export, list-manipulation, parallelization, histograms, logarithmic-scale

This question is related to [Export bug in combination with ParallelTable?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104310/export-bug-in-combination-with-paralleltable).

The following code shows an even stranger bug than in the upper question.

**The y-axis should always be logarithmic, but in the resulting plot files it jumps randomly between logarithmic and linear**. The linear axis numbers are wrong.

```
ChoiceDialog[{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[outputDir], "Directory"], Dynamic[outputDir]}];
SetDirectory[outputDir];

image = ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "Grayscale"];
levels = ImageLevels[image, "Byte"];
hist = Histogram[WeightedData @@ Transpose[levels], 256, 
   ScalingFunctions -> "Log", ImageSize -> 600];

ParallelTable[

  fileName = StringJoin[outputDir, "\\histogram_parallel_table_", ToString[i], ".png"];

  Export[fileName, hist, "PNG"],

  {i, 1, 10}

  ];
```

**This error does not occur when `Table` is used or when logarithmic scaling is removed.**

For one run I got e.g. the following two different plots (there are more):

`i=1`:

[image]

`i=6`:

[image]

I am programming with Mathematica 10.3.1.0 on Windows 10 Professional 64 Bit and have an i7-4940-MX 3,1 GHz processor (4 cores).

Comment: Possibly this is something to do with frontend rendering being used when Table is employed but kernel rendering when ParallelTable is invoked.

Comment: Can you reproduce that? In the `ParallelTable` description it says: `ParallelTable` will give the same results as `Table`, except for side effects during the computation. May be something has to be specified with `DistributedContexts`?

Comment: I'll try when home if I can.  Can you try this with ParallelTable replaced with ParallelEvaluate using $KernelID insted of your iterator i?

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the bug? How does the code exactly should look like, when `ParallelEvaluate` and `$KernelID ` are used?

Comment: Sorry, not had a chance to yet. ParallelEvaluate[fileName = StringJoin[outputDir, "\\histogram_parallel_table_", ToString[$KernelID], ".png"]; Export[fileName, hist, "PNG"]];  I don't suggest this as a solution but as a test to see if its ParallelTable specific rather than just something to do with being run in a parallel way.

Comment: This code produces errors: `(kernel1) StringJoin::string: String expected at position 1 in outputDir<>\histogram_parallel_table_1.png.` etc.

Comment: You have not defined outputDir.

Comment: I can not reproduce this w/10.1.

Comment: @george2079 Do you use 4 cores? As you see below Ymareth showed the same problem for the vertical scale.

Comment: @mrz, this is the same bug from the other questioin, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104310/9490.  Parallel kernels for some inane reason have trouble dealing with log ticks

Comment: yes 4 cores, and I actually ran Ymareth's code.

Comment: @Jason B After your answer and solution to the mentioned question I understand the problem or bug ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a workaround, which I found at

> example/OutOfCoreImageHistogramComputation

```
counts = ConstantArray[0, 256];

f[x_] := Block[{b = Clip[Floor[255*x + .5], {0, 255}]}, counts[[b + 1]]++];

image = ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "Grayscale"];

ImageScan[f, image];

BarChart[counts, BarSpacing -> 0, ImageSize -> 600, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]

ChoiceDialog[{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[outputDir], "Directory"], Dynamic[outputDir]}];
SetDirectory[outputDir];

ParallelTable[

 fileName = StringJoin[outputDir, "\\histogram_parallel_table_", ToString[i], ".png"];

 Export[fileName, plot, "PNG"], 

 {i, 1, 10}

];
```

All plots look the same and the vertical scale is always logarithmic.

For all `i`:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Confirmation rather than answer.  I'm not sure the original example is entirely functional, at least it was not for me.  Mine is...

```
SetDirectory["F:\\Temp"]; (* Adjust to suit your environment *)
hist = Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 10000], ScalingFunctions -> "Log", ImageSize -> 600]
```

Note log scale on y-axis in resulting histogram.

```
DistributeDefinitions[hist]; (*missing in original - seems necessary or remote kernels don't know what hist is.*)

ParallelEvaluate[Export[StringJoin["histogram_parallel_table_",ToString[$KernelID],".png"],hist,"PNG"]];
```

This gives me a log scale in all 8 versions produced BUT only the one from kernel 1 has the scaled labelled with log intervals (1,10,100,1000).  2-8 are labelled (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8); Ln(count).

From Kernel 1...

[image: From kernel 1]

From Kernels 2-8...

[image]

Comment: Running on 10.3.1 on Win 10

Comment: Thank you for you help ... this is strange ... I hope somebody can again look into that ...